# using jQuery to work with already change dom objects

Tags: jquery, html, dom

i have this code, which works fine when i am using it on html static elements, but when i change DOM with jquery, it not works.
I have tried to find some solution for something like this, but i can't.

So how to modify this code , to work with dom objects, not with html objects?

thank you a lot, have a nice day.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var Arrays=new Array();



$('.data').click(function(){

    var thisID = $(this).attr('id');

    var itemname  = $(this).find('.product').html();
    var itemprice = $(this).find('.price').html();

    if(include(Arrays,thisID))
    {
        var price    = $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-price").find('em').html();
        var quantity = $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-quantity").html();
        quantity = parseInt(quantity)+parseInt(1);

        var total = parseInt(itemprice)*parseInt(quantity);

        $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-price").find('em').html(total);
        $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-quantity").html(quantity);

        var prev_charges = $('.cart-total span').html();
        prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)-parseInt(price);

        prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)+parseInt(total);
        $('.cart-total span').html(prev_charges);

        $('#total-hidden-charges').val(prev_charges);
    }
    else
    {
        Arrays.push(thisID);

        var prev_charges = $('.cart-total span').html();
        prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)+parseInt(itemprice);

        $('.cart-total span').html(prev_charges);
        $('#total-hidden-charges').val(prev_charges);

        $('#left_bar .cart-info').append('<div class="shopp" id="each-'+thisID+'"><div class="label">'+itemname+'</div><div class="shopp-price"> $<em>'+itemprice+'</em></div><span class="shopp-quantity">1</span><img src="remove.png" class="remove" /><br class="all" /></div>');

        $('#cart').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)','-moz-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)' });
    }

    setTimeout('angle()',200);
}); 


$('.remove').livequery('click', function() {

    var deduct = $(this).parent().children(".shopp-price").find('em').html();
    var prev_charges = $('.cart-total span').html();

    var thisID = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('each-','');

    var pos = getpos(Arrays,thisID);
    Arrays.splice(pos,1,"0")

    prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)-parseInt(deduct);
    $('.cart-total span').html(prev_charges);
    $('#total-hidden-charges').val(prev_charges);
    $(this).parent().remove();

}); 

$('#Submit').livequery('click', function() {

    var totalCharge = $('#total-hidden-charges').val();

    $('#left_bar').html('Total Charges: $'+totalCharge);

    return false;

});
```

});

Comment: what doesn't work? what error do you get? please describe the behaviour that you expect to happen

Comment: instead .livequery try using just .live

Comment: removed my comment because it didn't make sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

can you please use [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) OR [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) OR [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)method after changes in DOM object

`bind()` :Attach a handler to an event for the elements.

`live()` :Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

`on()` : Above both are deprecated from newer version so its better to use `.on()`